# How can I adjust the color of a fixed element to its background elements color?

Tags: javascript, css

The situation is that I have a website with mutiple full-width content containers, stacked on the height axis (Y). Every second one of these is blue and every other second one of these is red. I want to show an SVG image or a button fixed in the top-left corner (that scrolls down with the user). The fill color of this element should be dynamically inverted to the underlying content containers background color. When the fixed element is hovering over two content containers at the same time its fill color must be split up accordingly.

When the user scrolls down, the fixed element (Circle in the image below this text) should adjust its fill color according to the background elements below. When the circle is fully over the red content container, it should be blue. When the circle is fully over the blue content container, it should be red. When it is over two content containers, it should split its fill color.

[image]

The idea was to have a fixed element with position:fixed for every content container and to limit its "visibility" with overflow-y:hidden on the content container, but as position:fixed attaches the elements viewport to the window/body, this solution does not seem to work.

The next idea was to use position:sticky. The fixed element successfully stopped at its content containers bottom line but exceeded it a bit and didn't have the sharp cut effect of hiding beyond the bottom line.

Another idea was to use the z-index property but as it is only one-dimensional, I believe it can't serve the purpose.

Below blue circle should adjust accordingly:

```css
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.bg {
  height: 200px
}

.bg-red {
  background-color: red;
}

.bg-blue {
  background-color: blue
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="fixed"></div>
  <div class="backgrounds">
    <div class="bg bg-red"></div>
    <div class="bg bg-blue"></div>
    <div class="bg bg-red"></div>
    <div class="bg bg-blue"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would be very glad about a hint which can lead me to finding a solution here.

Comment: can you show the html+css code used to create this? Also, please specify what you want to happen when the user scrolls down

Comment: Maybe https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode

Comment: Thank you, I edited my post. @epascarello Can you please provide an example for my updated post? I tried it and didn't succeed so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your bg colors are 'pure' red and blue this is possible with mix-blend-mode difference.

Make the circle have background color #ff00ff. Then the difference with blue (#0000ff) is #ff0000 which is red and vice versa.

```css
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: #ff00ff;
  /*ADDED*/
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  
}

.bg {
  height: 200px
}

.bg-red {
  background-color: red;
}

.bg-blue {
  background-color: blue
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="fixed"></div>
  <div class="backgrounds">
    <div class="bg bg-red"></div>
    <div class="bg bg-blue"></div>
    <div class="bg bg-red"></div>
    <div class="bg bg-blue"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very for your answer! For me the blue and red colors of the circle are not perfect but it does the job well enough :)

Comment: Hi, I used the background colors as in the question (which made it easy as its obvious what their differences are). Are you actually using different colors than the ones in the question?

Comment: When I load your code snippet, the colors of the circle work fine (pure red+blue). But when I scroll a bit on the site and come back, the blue is more like a lightblue and the red is more like an orange. This must be a bug in my browser. Please excuse my previous dissatisfaction, everything is perfect.

Comment: gosh, that is really weird. Works OK for me scrolling back (Edge on Windows).